# most likely due to a circular import - Preciso fazer um programa multi telas, de forma que de cada tela possa voltar ao menu

Tags: python, tkinter

No entanto, cada tela está em um uma classe diferente e em um arquivo diferente, quando tento voltar ao menu vai ocorrer o erro de círculo. Qual a melhor forma de resolver?
Segue o código de cada arquivo:

#### Main

```
from tkinter import *
from primeira import *
class main():
    def __init__(self):
        self.master = Tk()

        # Configuração da janela principal
        self.master.title('Janela Principal')
        self.master.geometry('480x240')
        self.master.configure(borderwidth=4, background='white')

        self.button = Button(self.master, text='tela 1', command= lambda: self.evento())
        self.button.pack(side='left', fill='x')

        self.master.mainloop()

    def evento(self):
        self.master.destroy()
        FirstWindow()
main()
```

#### Primeira tela (em outro arquivo)

```
from tkinter import *
from main import main
class FirstWindow():
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        master = Tk()
        self.master = master

        # Configuração da janela principal
        self.master.title('Primeira Janela')
        self.master.configure(background='green')
        self.master.geometry('480x240')

        self.button = Button(master, text='menu', command= lambda: self.irMain())
        self.button.pack(side='left', fill='x', expand=True)
        master.mainloop()

    def irMain(self):
        self.master.destroy()
        main()
```

Comment: Esse problema acontece quando o arquivo A importa o arquivo B, e o arquivo B importa o arquivo A. As formas de corrigir isso são 1) colocar todo o código em um só arquivo, ou 2) reestruturar parte do código de um dos arquivos, de forma que não haja mais necessidade de fazer uma das duas importações.

Answer (score 0):

Nunca usei o tkinter mas com o kivymd eu faço assim:

não importo o Main na PrimeiraTela

e na PrimaeiraTela.py faço.

from kivymd.app import MDApp

(...)

app = MDApp.get_running_app()

app.GerenciadorDeTelas.current = 'MinhaTela'

o GerenciadorDeTelas é ScreenManager()

Veja algo parecido no tkinter

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Certo, vou dar uma pesquisada, obrigada!